# Ember js login without token

Tags: session, ember.js, authentication, electron, offline

Initially I would like to inform you that I am using ember 2.10.

Can anyone tell me how to make a login system without a token?
I am developing an offline application with Ember and Electron and I need to make the login system without using external APIs.

Comment: You need to clarify what you're asking, this question is far to vague. If you  don't have an API what do you want to login to?

Comment: I want make a complete login system with ember (only) to work offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to create an application that will support few users. It is possible. You will need to perform following steps:

1. Install [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) plugin. It makes auth-related things much easier
2. Create custom authenticator that will take a login and password or something from your users and save some identifier in session
3. Create login and register routes, where users will be able to login or create new credentials
4. Most probably you will not need an authorizer, because you don't have server api and don't send requests to it

Bear in mind that this will be zero-security system, even if you will use some encryption, because js code is not secured well from exploration. Also bear in mind that electron most probably stores user's data in user's home directory (I can't say for sure as I didn't work with electron, but node-webkit does that). In this case having different windows (or what OS your users will use) users is enough to separate data and you actually don't need any login system.